# Our 3 month old wakes up almost every hour through the night and wants to breastfeed only to wake up again 1 hour to half hour later

Tags: sleep

We are new parents to our first baby boy. When we got home from the hospital 3 1/2 months ago, our baby cried a lot when put down, and just wanted to be held. He hated swaddling so after trying every swaddle we unswaddled.

Now fast forward 3 months, 12 days and our baby is waking up 6 to 7 times after 1 am looking to be fed, sometimes every hour to half hour.

They won't sleep through the night. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is perfectly normal. Babies need to feed very frequently. Please look at the related questions listed to the right

Comment: I'll close as a dupe of the closest one